# Spline graph in grouped data in subgroup

Tags: highcharts, grouping

[image]is it possible to achieve this? I need to draw a spline/line over Category-Subcategory on X-axis.

[highcharts-grouped-data-in-subgroup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16442421/highcharts-grouped-data-in-subgroup) This link solved my Category-SubCateogry series on X-axis on HighCharts.

now, I want to draw spline(Line) on same graph *wrt* to category i.e **Agg1 & Agg2** as shown in diagram but when I tried draw line on graph it get plot *wrt* **(Data1 Data2) (Data1 Data2 Data3)**.........i.e get plot wrt SubCateogy not by Category

If such example is exists please share.

Comment: Have you tried groupCategories plugin which Pawel mentioned in the related topic?

Comment: Yes, I have used it. I got column chart perfectly but when I am trying to plot spline on same and I am facing issue for spline. Spline chart get plot as per "SubCategory" not by "Category"

Comment: Can you recreate? Becuase this http://jsfiddle.net/TFhd7/193/ example works as the same as line / column etc.

Comment: If you can post an image of what you want, and a working example of the result you are getting instead, that would be very helpful.

Comment: @SebastianBochan thanks for reply you plot line graph for subCateogy(apple,banana,orange,carrot.....) but I want to plot graph as for Category(**Fruit,Vegi,Fish**) and I have update the image in question for same.

Comment: So you need to add extra serie, which point will be calculated. You can extract each point from serie object.

Comment: That is the question how to plot? because whenever I am trying to add new series for line it get plot for **subcategory** ... How to define such series which will get plot for **Category**